# ASP.net - C# Hide/Show Controls when Button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

2everyone! I need your help..
I want to create static rows with button click event in Page_Load method(CreateChildControls). When I click "Create" и want to visualize the same row under the existing

T**his is my UI:**
[image]
**This is my code:**

```
public class HelloWorldWeb : WebPart
{
    private TextBox txt11;
    private DateTimeControl dt11;
    private DateTimeControl dt12;
    private TextBox txt12;
    private TextBox txt13;
    private Button btn1;

    private TextBox txt21;
    private DateTimeControl dt21;
    private DateTimeControl dt22;
    private TextBox txt22;
    private TextBox txt23;
    private Button btn2;

    //private TextBox txt31;
    //private DateTimeControl dt31;
    //private DateTimeControl dt132;
    //private TextBox txt32;
    //private TextBox txt33;
    //private Button btn3;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        txt11 = new TextBox();
        txt12 = new TextBox();
        txt13 = new TextBox();
        dt11 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt11.DateOnly = true;
        dt12 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt12.DateOnly = true;
        btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Text = "Create";
        btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);


        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table class='ms-formbody' vAlign='top' >"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100' >"));
        this.Controls.Add(txt11);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(dt11);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(dt12);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(txt12);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(txt13);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(btn1);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));

        if (btn1WasClicked)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100' >"));
            this.Controls.Add(txt21);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(dt21);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(dt22);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(txt22);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(txt23);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(btn2);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
        }

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }


    private bool btn1WasClicked = false;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1WasClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to check button is clicked?

Comment: My solution doesnt working;

Comment: Use databinding, with DataGrid

Comment: Please give me more info for this soluton...

Comment: It's hard to answer precisely because the subject si very complex. You have to follow some tutorial related to databinding. You allso have to understand the page lifecycle - and the stateless nature of html pages. You can't "persist" controls creation across postback, because each time the page load, the page is rebuilt from scratch. That's the point of databinding... feed databound control with datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Add the code to add a new row to the event handler instead of using it in `CreateChildControls`:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add a new row
}
```

Like this you can add a new row when the button is clicked and don't have to use a boolean variable `btn1WasClicked`.

Answer (score 0):

diiN_ is right just put your whole code in side if(btn1WasClicked) under btn1_Click

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Add a new row
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100' >"));
  this.Controls.Add(txt21);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
  this.Controls.Add(dt21);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
  this.Controls.Add(dt22);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
  this.Controls.Add(txt22);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
  this.Controls.Add(txt23);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100'>"));
  this.Controls.Add(btn2);
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
}
```